# AWS API Gateway: deny traffic based on source IP addresses from managed prefix lists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

Organisation provides me with a bunch of VPC managed prefix lists, representing VPN gateways and internal hosts from different regions.

These (and only these) IPs have to have access to a REST API gateway.

I currently list them in a resource policy like below, copying addresses to array manually.

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:myapiarn/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "IpAddress": {
                        "aws:SourceIp": ["f.o.o/28", "b.a.r/24" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Question is: can I reference managed prefix list directly from resource policy?

Are there alternative ways to achieve this? External tools, e.g. Terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question, then yes, it can be done using the [`api_gateway_rest_api_policy` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_rest_api_policy). To reference the prefix lists that exist outside of terraform, the [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ec2_managed_prefix_list#example-usage) for getting the prefix lists can be used. Based on the JSON snippet and using an example from the data source documentation, something like this could be used:

```
data "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "foo" {
  name = "foo-prefix-list"
}

data "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "bar" {
  name = "bar-prefix-list"
}
```

Then, if you were to use the terraform resource, you would do the following

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "api_gateway_resource_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }

    actions   = ["execute-api:Invoke"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:execute-api:myapiarn/*"]

    condition {
      test     = "IpAddress"
      variable = "aws:SourceIp"
      values   = concat(data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.foo.entries[*].cidr, data.aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.bar.entries[*].cidr)
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy" "api_gateway_resource_policy" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.your_api.id
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.api_gateway_resource_policy.json
}
```

Comment: This looks like a way to translate what I currently do into Terraform. Question is: how do I reference externally created VPC managed prefix list IPs from there?

Comment: When you say externally, where exactly are those prefix lists defined?

Comment: In 'AWS VPC' -> 'managed prefix lists'. Externally means they're provided as a part of my AWS account and are maintained by someone else, so I can't rely on them being static.